# Python 2 Ubuntu default, pip, and virtualenv

Tags: default-programs, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

https://packaging.python.org/installing/#install-pip-setuptools-and-wheel

“If you have Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4 installed from python.org, you will already have pip and setuptools, “

Maybe, maybe not:

I do have pip2 and Python 2.7.10 and 2.7.12. The latter is my current system default. I am on Ubuntu 16.04. Apparently I don’t have pip2 installed systemwide. I can create a new venv by using pip2 from inside a pre-existing venv:

```
(cannon)malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/cannon$ pyvenv Projects/memory
(cannon)malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/cannon$ cd New2.7Projects/memory
(cannon)malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/cannon/New2.7Projects/memory$ deactivate
note change of outer folder name
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/cannon/New2.7Projects/memory$ source bin/activate
(memory) malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/cannon/New2.7Projects/memory$
```

However,

```
(memory) malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/cannon/New2.7Projects/memory$ pip list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: No module named 'pip'
(memory) malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/cannon/New2.7Projects/memory$ pip2 list
The program 'pip2' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install python-pip
```

This suggests I have Python 2 only from Ubuntu and that it does NOT have pip (or pip2, or virtualenv, or pyvenv) installed by default, even though it is newer than 2.7.9. Is this correct? Why? And if not, how do I call pip?

If you’re going to tell me to curl it from pypi:

```
malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/cannon$ sudo -H curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python
[sudo] password for malikarumi: 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1558k  100 1558k    0     0   626k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  626k

...< some nonsense about pip and sudo’s -H flag which I have followed but which changes nothing. Note that on this particular attempt the -H flag is there>...

Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /home/malikarumi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

What am I supposed to do here? Thanks.

--update-- My mistake. The venv I created has Python 3.4 in it. I thought by default if you create a venv from within a certain interpreter/version, you would automatically get that interpreter/version, but that's not what happened here. I am even more mystified because 3.4 is not my system default. I don't know what happened there, but obviously I still need help with a 2.7 venv and pip. Thanks